# Saving files in disk

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I want to save the files as pdf,jpeg,txt,gif etc to disk from database. In database it is stored as binary data. How can I do it? Is it possible with using memory stream?

Answer (score 0):

bcp "your_query for selecting the row" queryout "c:\TestOut.doc" -T -n

this link should help you:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic487470-338-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you read it from the database it comes in as an object that holds and array of bytes.

Cast it to an array of bytes and create a stream with it.

In C#

```
byte[] content =(byte[])data; // data the database field. e.g. reader["MyPicture"]
return new MemoryStream(content);
```

After that FileStream will do the saving for you.

Don't forget to seek the beginning, before you save.